# iPod 5 to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipod

I have an iPod 5. If I block an iPhone user (not sure if the type matters) will they still be able to see the conversations && messages we had before I blocked them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the old messages will still be there. All blocking them does is ensure that you don't receive any more calls, texts, or FaceTime Audio calls from them.